# Swift: using a for loop to insert items. At the end, when i query it shows only the value which was inserted last at each index

Tags: arrays, swift

In Swift playground, I'm using a for loop to insert items. During the loop it seems to be adding the right values. At the end of the for loop, when the array is all filled up, when I query, it shows only the value which was inserted last at each index.

New to swift, so I guess am doing something really stupid here... Need help...

The code is as below:

```
class card {
  var suit: String = ""
  var rank: String = ""
}

var card1 = card()
var deck = [card]()
var playingCard = card()

var suits = ["♠︎","♣︎","♥︎","♦︎"]
var ranks = ["A","K","Q","J","10","9","8","7","6","5","4","3","2"]

let countRanks = ranks.count
let countSuits = suits.count
var ctr = 0
for i in 0..<countSuits {
  for j in 0..<countRanks {
    playingCard.rank = ranks[j]
    playingCard.suit = suits[i]
    deck.insert(playingCard, atIndex: 0)
    println("\(deck[ctr].suit)"+"\(deck[ctr].rank)")
    ctr++
  }
}

let x = deck.count
for i in 0..<x {
  println("\(deck[i].rank)"+"\(deck[i].suit)")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

class instances are reference types. You need to create a new card instance for each iteration. Move the line `var playingCard = card()` right after the `for j in 0..<countRanks` line and change `var` to `let`

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Though am still not sure why I need to create a new instance for each iteration.

Comment: your original code is changing suit and rank always of the same object and the same object is inserted 52 times.

Comment: @Ashish in Swift a class type is a reference type. When you create your array you are not putting the cards into the array. You are putting references to the cards in the array. Now, because you only have one card you have the same reference being entered over and over. And when you change the values in the card it changes the one actual card that all the references point to.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialise a new instance of playingCard each iteration:

```
for i in 0..<countSuits {
  for j in 0..<countRanks {
    var playingCard = card()
    ...
  }
}
```

I would also suggest you add an init method for your card class to make it easier to initialise:

```
class Card {
  var suit: String
  var rank: String
  init(suit: String, rank: String) {
    self.suit = suit
    self.rank = rank
  }
}

...

var playingCard = Card(suit: suits[i], rank: ranks[j])
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I had initially tried append but didn't help. Creating a new instance for each iteration worked.